# Show that the functions are vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the subspace of $C^1(\mathbb R)$ spanned by $f(x) = \sin x $ and $g(x) = \cos x$.

a) Show that for any constant value of $\theta$, the functions $f_1(x)=\sin (x+ \theta) $ and $f_2(x)= \cos (x+ \theta)$ are vectors in $V$.

I think I should test the axioms of closed under addition, closed under scalar multiplication and zero identity etc. But I'm not sure how to combine the $\theta$ into the equation? Do I need to use trigonometric formulas?

Comment: Use the [sum rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) for $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to use the trigonometric formulas to show that you can write those as a linear combination of the sine and the cosine and consequently vectors in that vector space.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to prove that some set is a vector space, you are *given* a certain vector space $V$ to start with, namely the set of all linear combinations of $\cos$ and $\sin$, i.e., the set of all functions $f(x):= A\cos x+B\sin x$, where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary real constants.

In addition two special functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are given, and you are asked to prove that they lie in $V$. So the question is: Are there real constants $A$ and $B$ such that  one has
$$f_1(x):=\sin(x+\theta)\equiv A\cos x+ B\sin x \qquad\forall x\in{\mathbb R}\ ,$$
and similarly for $f_2$, where $\theta$ is a given and fixed phase shift.